# Battleship game board in Java

Tags: java

I write the code of the warships game. There are two players, human and computer players. Both of them have separate boards. In the beginning, I automatically place the ships on both boards randomly, then I take the coordinates and put the ships on each other's boards.If the place in the coordinate hits the other player's ship, I will send a message saying this to the screen. The character "s" is shown on the screen if it sinks the ship, only with "*" if it hits and "x" if it cannot hit. How can I make changes to the computer player's board after receiving coordinates when it's time for the human player?

```
public static int numRows = 10;
public static int numCols = 10;
public static int playerShips;
public static int computerShips;
public static String[][] grid = new String[numRows][numCols];
public static int[][] missedGuesses = new int[numRows][numCols];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Amiral Batti game");
    System.out.println("\nComputer: ");
    deployComputerShips();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("\nHuman: ");
    deployPlayerShips();

    do {
        Battle();
    }
    while(players.playerShips != 0 && players.computerShips != 0);

    gameOver();
}
public static int FIELD_SIZE = 10;

public static void deployPlayerShips() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[][] field = new int[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        int x = random.nextInt(field.length);
        int y = random.nextInt(field.length);
        boolean vertical = random.nextBoolean();

        if (vertical) {
            if (y + i > FIELD_SIZE) {
                y -= i;
            }
        } else if (x + i > FIELD_SIZE) {
            x -= i;
        }
        boolean isFree = true;

        if (vertical) {
            for (int m = y; m < y + i; m++) {
                if (field[m][x] != 0) {
                    isFree = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int n = x; n < x + i; n++) {
                if (field[y][n] != 0) {
                    isFree = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isFree) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (vertical) {
            for (int m = Math.max(0, x - 1); m < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, x + 2); m++) {
                for (int n = Math.max(0, y - 1); n < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, y + i + 1); n++) {
                    field[n][m] = 9;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int m = Math.max(0, y - 1); m < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, y + 2); m++) {
                for (int n = Math.max(0, x - 1); n < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, x + i + 1); n++) {
                    field[m][n] = 9;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            field[y][x] = i;
            if (vertical) {
                y++;
            } else {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    char[][] map = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
            map[i][j] = field[i][j] == 0 || field[i][j] == 9 ? '.' : 'o';
        }
    }

    Arrays.stream(map)
            .forEach(m -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m).replace(",", "")));
}
public static void deployComputerShips() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[][] field = new int[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {

        int x = random.nextInt(field.length);
        int y = random.nextInt(field.length);
        boolean vertical = random.nextBoolean();

        if (vertical) {
            if (y + i > FIELD_SIZE) {
                y -= i;
            }
        } else if (x + i > FIELD_SIZE) {
            x -= i;
        }

        boolean isFree = true;

        if (vertical) {
            for (int m = y; m < y + i; m++) {
                if (field[m][x] != 0) {
                    isFree = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int n = x; n < x + i; n++) {
                if (field[y][n] != 0) {
                    isFree = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isFree) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (vertical) {
            for (int m = Math.max(0, x - 1); m < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, x + 2); m++) {
                for (int n = Math.max(0, y - 1); n < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, y + i + 1); n++) {
                    field[n][m] = 9;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int m = Math.max(0, y - 1); m < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, y + 2); m++) {
                for (int n = Math.max(0, x - 1); n < Math.min(FIELD_SIZE, x + i + 1); n++) {
                    field[m][n] = 9;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            field[y][x] = i;
            if (vertical) {
                y++;
            } else {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    char[][] map = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
            map[i][j] = field[i][j] == 0 || field[i][j] == 9 ? '.' : 'o';
        }
    }

    Arrays.stream(map)
            .forEach(m -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m).replace(",", "")));
}

public static void Battle(){
    playerTurn();
    computerTurn();

    printBoard();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Your ships: " + players.playerShips + " | Computer ships: " + players.computerShips);
    System.out.println();
}

public static void playerTurn(){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nHuman's turn: ");
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter row number: ");
        x = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter column number: ");
        y = scn.nextInt();

        if ((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols)){
            if (grid[x][y].equals("o")){
                System.out.println("You sunk the ship!");
                grid[x][y] = "s";
                --players.computerShips;
            }
            else if (grid[x][y].equals(".")) {
                System.out.println("You missed");
                grid[x][y] = "x";
            }
        }
        else if ((x < 0 || x >= numRows) || (y < 0 || y >= numCols))
            System.out.println("You can't place ships outside the " + numRows + " by " + numCols + " grid");
    }
    while((x < 0 || x >= numRows) || (y < 0 || y >= numCols));
}
public static void computerTurn(){
    System.out.println("\nComputer's turn: ");

    int x = -1, y = -1;
    do {
        x = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        y = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("Enter row number: "+x);
        System.out.println("Enter column number: "+y);

        if ((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols)){
            if (grid[x][y].equals("o")){
                System.out.println("The Computer sunk one of your ships!");
                grid[x][y] = "s";
                --players.playerShips;
                ++players.computerShips;
            }
            else if (grid[x][y].equals(".")) {
                System.out.println("Computer missed");
                grid[x][y] = "x";
                if(missedGuesses[x][y] != 1)
                    missedGuesses[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while((x < 0 || x >= numRows) || (y < 0 || y >= numCols));
}

public static void gameOver(){
    System.out.println("Your ships: " + players.playerShips + " | Computer ships: " + players.computerShips);
    if(players.playerShips > 0 && players.computerShips <= 0)
        System.out.println("You won the battle! ");
    else
        System.out.println("You lost the battle! ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printBoard(){

    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("0123456789");

    for(int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(x);

        for (int y = 0; y < grid[x].length; y++){
            System.out.print(grid[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code and the problem so that it's a little clearer? That would help me (and perhaps others?) a lot.

Comment: Side note: create ***one*** `Scanner` object based on `System.in` for the entire application and pass it where needed. Otherwise you run into unnecessary risk.

Comment: I hope it is clear right now. @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: Have you created classes for the GameBoard, the grid that holds the ships? That's the first thing that I'd do: create a class that holds perhaps a gird of chars with a char indicating if a ship is there, if it has been hit, etc... and give it public methods to allow other classes to fire a shot at a location on the grid,.... It's all about getting everything as object-oriented as possible.

Comment: On my side its not clear yet. We need more details and/or more code and a precise question if you want help.

Comment: I shared the entire code but it is not finished so I still have errors. @bsaverino

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot clearer and I already understand why you seems stuck. I cannot fully answer now but I can already say that you need a loop in method Battle() and no loops in player/computerTurn() methods. You also need to make the field(s) variables global/static and not keep them inside method() as their scope is only local to the methods for the moment (and state is lost when exitting method).

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for having 'accepted' the answer.

Comment: I started Java this year. Our teacher gave this project, but it is difficult for beginners, for me. So I have to get help to pass the lesson. Thank you for your answer. @bsaverino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is a more correct version. I could do more but ... then half of the code would be rewritten and I don't see the point of doing that (doesn't help you). So I insist that its **far from perfect** but at least it resolves your issue. I made the following corrections:

- The battle() method has a corrected game logic
- I removed the 'grid' variable. I don't understand why it exists. And instead externalized the 'field' variable -> one for each player.
- I merged your two *deployPlayerShips()* *deployComputerShips()* methods into one: *deployPlayersShips(...)*. But I still don't understand most of its logic. And with the given code below there are issues at display and field init. But these errors certainly are already present in your original code.
- I have rewritten printBoard() to make use of 'field' variables. But it will still need fixes.
- I fixed partially the playerTurn() and computerTurn() methods as they had badly constructed loops. Turns could never really "turn". **The biggest (blocking) problem was in these methods** I think (even though other errors remain).
- I've added a global Random() and made Scanner instantiated only once.

package sandbox;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

// ATTENTION: low-quality code based on original source posted in question. Not fully functional and has many issues. But it answers the original question.
public class Warships {

    private static final int numRows = 10;
    private static final int numCols = 10;
    private static final int NB_SHIPS = 5;

    private static int playerShips = NB_SHIPS;
    private static int computerShips = NB_SHIPS;
    private static final int[][] missedGuesses = new int[numRows][numCols];

    private static final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static final int FIELD_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int[][] playerField = new int[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
    private static final int[][] computerField = new int[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Amiral Batti game");

        System.out.println("\nComputer: ");
        deployPlayersShips(computerField);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("\nHuman: ");
        deployPlayersShips(playerField);

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);  

        do {
            battle(scn);
        } while (playerShips != 0 && computerShips != 0);

        gameOver();
    }

    public static void deployPlayersShips(int[][] field) {       
        for (int i = NB_SHIPS; i > 0; i--) {
            int x = random.nextInt(field.length);
            int y = random.nextInt(field.length);
            boolean vertical = random.nextBoolean();

            (...)
        }    
        printBoard2(field);
    }

    public static void battle(Scanner scn) {                                          
            playerTurn(scn);
            computerTurn();

            System.out.println("\nComputer: ");
            printBoard2(computerField);
            System.out.println("\nHuman: ");
            printBoard2(playerField);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Your ships: " + playerShips + " | Computer ships: " + computerShips);
            System.out.println();
    }

    public static void playerTurn(Scanner scn) {        
        System.out.println("\nHuman's turn: ");
        int x = -1, y = -1;

        // MAIN ISSUE WAS HERE -- Add correct loop on invalid input
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter row number: ");
            x = scn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter column number: ");
            y = scn.nextInt();
        } while ((x < 0 || x >= numRows) || (y < 0 || y >= numCols));

        // MAIN ISSUE WAS HERE -- Removed invalid loop on update field
        if (computerField[x][y] != 0 && computerField[x][y] != 9) {
            System.out.println("You sunk the ship!");
            computerField[x][y] = 1;//"s";
            computerShips--;
        } else if (".".equals(computerField[x][y])) {
            System.out.println("You missed");
            computerField[x][y] = 2; //"x";
        }                   
    }

    public static void computerTurn() {
        System.out.println("\nComputer's turn: ");

        int x = random.nextInt(FIELD_SIZE);
        int y = random.nextInt(FIELD_SIZE);
        System.out.println("Enter row number: " + x);
        System.out.println("Enter column number: " + y);

        // MAIN ISSUE WAS HERE -- Removed invalid loop on input/rand
        if ((x >= 0 && x < numRows) && (y >= 0 && y < numCols)) {
            if (playerField[x][y] != 0 && playerField[x][y] != 9) {
                System.out.println("The Computer sunk one of your ships!");
                playerField[x][y] = 1;//"s";
                playerShips--;
            } else if (".".equals(playerField[x][y])) {
                System.out.println("Computer missed");
                playerField[x][y] = 2; //"x";
                if (missedGuesses[x][y] != 1) {
                    missedGuesses[x][y] = 1;
                }
            }              
        }
    }

    public static void gameOver() {
        System.out.println("Your ships: " + playerShips + " | Computer ships: " + computerShips);
        if (playerShips > 0 && computerShips <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You won the battle! ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You lost the battle! ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printBoard2(int[][] field) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
        char[][] map = new char[FIELD_SIZE][FIELD_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
                switch(field[i][j]) {
                    case 0:
                    case 9: map[i][j] = '.';
                        break;
                    case 1: map[i][j] = 's';
                        break;
                    case 2: map[i][j] = 'x';
                        break;
                    default: map[i][j] = 'o';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        Arrays.stream(map)
                .forEach(m -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m).replace(",", "")));
    }
}
```

At this point  **I let you do the rest. Many errors remain**. Take the time to truly finish and double-check your code before requesting help again. And keep training there is room for improvements out there in terms of OOP, coding rules and best practices. Good luck.

Comment: I started Java this year. Our teacher gave this project, but it is difficult for beginners, for me. So I have to get help to pass the lesson. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. In this game, after the two players have placed their ships, they will shoot each other's board and mutually sink the ships. what should i do for this?

Comment: Now you need to think object-oriented. That's the power of Java, C# and C++ (among others). Define multiple classes or entities: ship, player, board, score, etc. With all your objects, accessors and proper methods you will slowly start to manipulate them smartly. If you define a Ship class then you may imagine it as an object with multiple coordinates and once all of its coordinates were hit, its sunk (and disappear from the Board (instance)). That's the next steps.

Comment: But honestly and to spare you some disappointment, this site is the wrong place to answer these questions. Be sure to have done enough research and come up with a specific and - if possible - unique problem before asking on StackOverlow. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic